# why would a date comparison involving DATE_ADD in mysql fail, but comparing as strings work?

Tags: mysql, date

I have isolated my problem to the following.

Using this clause retrieves no results

```
WHERE dtmDateTime = DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('2015-08-21 ', StartTime), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i'), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

but this clause retrieves the results I expect

```
DATE_FORMAT(dtmDateTime, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i') = DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('2015-08-21 ', StartTime), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i'), INTERVAL 1 DAY), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i')
```

the difference being that I have simply converted two dates to their string equivalents. Now of course to do so I have to specify a format, so logic would suggest the dates are different in some way, but identical when formatted: perhaps in the number of seconds, for example, but adding ':%s' to the format string certainly makes no difference, and I don't believe the dates *are* different.

Here is the full code context of the query (it's still very stripped down, but it shows where "StartTime" comes from)

```
SELECT StartTime AS ID, StartTime, (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(intActivityID) FROM tblBookings B WHERE dtmDateTime = DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('2015-08-21 ', StartTime), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i'), INTERVAL 1 DAY)) AS `Sat`

FROM (SELECT '10:00' AS StartTime UNION SELECT '10:30' UNION SELECT '11:00' UNION SELECT '11:30' UNION SELECT '12:00' UNION SELECT '12:30' UNION SELECT '13:00' UNION SELECT '13:30' UNION SELECT '14:00' UNION SELECT '14:30' UNION SELECT '15:00' UNION SELECT '15:30' UNION SELECT '16:00') AS X
```

I don't think the data is significant. I believe the problem lies with DATE_ADD. If I change the supplied date to '2015-08-22', and remove the DATE_ADD, then I don't need the DATE_FORMAT for the comparison to provide the expected results. What does DATE_ADD do that would explain this behaviour?

dtmDateTime is indeed a DATETIME column containing arbitrary values

Comment: I think the format parameter of date_format, and the closing parenthesis, in the right value of the second query are missing in your question. Can you please edit ?

Comment: Can we assume that dtmDateTime is a DATETIME column containing arbitrary values ?

Comment: Or maybe dtmDateTime is a (VAR)CHAR (explaining why you str_to_date it) and maybe DATE_FORMAT is not part of the right value of the second query, because you didnt wrote it in the third ?